# Access Command OutputInterface within a Doctrine Fixtures Load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, command

I'm generating a huge amount of data fixtures using the awesome [Faker Library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker), also using [lorempixel.com](http://www.lorempixel.com) to have some random images in my Symfony2 project. This takes some time (currently ~ 10 Minutes), so I was wondering if it is possible to access the **Command OutputInterface** somehow through the container interface and print the progress this way instead of `echo'ing` everything..

Maybe also to have a nice output with [ProgressBar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html)

Comment: I'm updating a large database in a `DoctrineMigration` class and I would like to have a progress bar. Did you found any solution to this question?

Comment: unfortunately not using DoctrineMigrations - the only suitable way I found is to write your own Command and implement the logic there instead of a migration class..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like [ConsoleOutput](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Output/ConsoleOutput.php#L44) doesn't need anything special and can be instantiated directly.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

// ...

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();

    $output->writeln('<info>this works... </info>');
}
```

Comment: after so long time. I didn't even try to simply create an instance of `ConsoleOutput` - thank you for solving this mystery

Comment: There is a typo in <info>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little bit better solution if you get the "original" `$output` object, using the `ConsoleEvents::COMMAND` event.

```php
namespace App\DoctrineFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CustomFixture extends AbstractFixture implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var OutputInterface */
    private $output;

    /** @var Command */
    private $command;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ConsoleEvents::COMMAND => 'init',
        ];
    }

    public function init(ConsoleCommandEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->output = $event->getOutput();
        $this->command = $event->getCommand();
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // ...
        $this->output->writeln('...');
        // ...
        $tableHelper = $this->command->getHelper('table');
        // ...
        $progressBar = new ProgressBar($this->output, 50);
        // ...
    }
}
```

In `services.yml`:

```
services:
    App\DoctrineFixtures\CustomFixture:
        tags:
            - 'doctrine.fixture.orm'
            - 'kernel.event_subscriber'
```